# Deleting a specific row using codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, delete-row

Thank you for all the help and suggestions. Here's my answer to my problem:

**view**

```
<td><a href ="<?php echo site_url('helloworld/delete/'.$row->user_no);?>">delete</a></td>
```

**controller**

```
function delete($user_no) { 
    $this->load->model("dbmodel");
    $this->dbmodel->delete_row($user_no);

}
```

**model**

```
public function delete_row($id){
    $this -> db -> where('user_no', $id);
    $this -> db -> delete('users');
    redirect('helloworld/');
}
```

I hope this can help you :)

---

I am new in codeigniter. I'm trying to delete a specific row but I always get this error:

> 404 Page Not Found
>
> The page you requested was not found.

Here is my code in my **view**:

```
<td><?php echo anchor('helloworld/delete_row?id='.$row->user_no, 'DELETE', 'id="$row->user_no"'); ?></td>
```

**model**:

```
function row_delete($id) {    
    $this->db->where('user_no', $id);   
    $this->db->delete('users');
}
```

**controller**:

```
function delete_row(){
    $id = $this->input->get('id');
    $this->load->model('dbmodel');
    $this->dbmodel->row_delete($id);
}
```

Comment: Can you specify steps needed to reproduce the error you're getting, e.g. the URL it's produced at?

Comment: I have this in my URL: http://localhost/ci/index.php/helloworld/delete_row/id/5

It can get the id that I want to delete but it says that the page I'm requesting was not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add directly an anchor

```
<a href ="<?php echo site_url('controller/delete/'.$row->user_no);?>">delete</a>
or
<?php echo anchor('controller/delete/'.$row->user_no, 'Delete','title="delete"');?>
```

model function :-

```
public function deleteRecord($table, $where = array()) {
  $this->db->where($where);
  $res = $this->db->delete($table); 
  if($res)
    return TRUE;
  else
    return FALSE;
}
```

controller :-

```
public function delete($id = '') {
  $this->load->model('dbmodel');
  $where = array('user_no' => $id); 
  $this->dbmodel->deleteRecord('table_name',$where);
}
```

Comment: undefined variable id

Comment: need to send $row->user_no instead of $id check updated

Comment: means you not id exist where you calling anchor

Comment: your url will be localhost/ci/index.php/helloworld/delete/5 try to paste it in browser and check row is deleted or not

Answer (score 0):

Try this while generating the anchor tag:-

```
<?php echo anchor('helloworld/delete_row/id/'.$row->user_no, 'DELETE', "id='".$row->user_no."'"); ?>
```

Here, I am assuming that helloworld will be the name of your controller.

Comment: Yes, helloworld is my controller. I tried your suggestion but still got the same error.

I have this in my URL: http://localhost/ci/index.php/helloworld/delete_row/id/5

Comment: Make Sure that your controller name start with capital letter like this public class Helloworld

Comment: Yes, my controller starts with a capital letter. Same error though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

**View**

```
<td><?php echo anchor('helloworld/delete_row/'.$row->user_no, 'DELETE', 'id="$row->user_no"'); ?></td>
```

**Controller**

```
function delete_row($id){
    $this->load->model('dbmodel');
    $this->dbmodel->row_delete($id);
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion sir but I still get the same error though.