# Codeigniter: delete data

Tags: php, codeigniter, delete-row, codeigniter-url

I have a problem on my code, I'm trying to delete some data from my database via delete button in codeigniter.. this my view:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/m_pakar/delete');?>/<?php echo 
$result['pakar_id'];?>"<i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a>
```

This code in my controller:

```
public function delete() {

    $datasend = array(
            'class'=>'',
            'message'=>'',
        );

    $id = $this->input->post("id", TRUE);
    $this->general->set_table('data_pakar');
    $this->general->where(array('pakar_id' => $id));

    $deletepakar = $this->general->delete();
    if ($deletepakar) {         
        $datasend = array(
                    'class'=>'class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable"',
                    'message'=>'<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" 
                    aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Data berhasil dihapus.',
        );
    } else {

        $datasend = array(
                    'class'=>'class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"',
                    'message'=>'<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" 
                    aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Data gagal dihapus.',
        );
    }

    $datasend['pakar'] = $this->general->get_result_array();
    $datasend['level'] = $this->general->get_result_array();

    $dataview['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/m_pakar/index', $datasend, TRUE);
    $this->load->view($this->template, $dataview);

}
```

And this my model:

```
public function delete() {

    $delete = $this->db->delete($this->tbname);
    return $delete;
}
```

With this code, `$deletepakar = $this->general->delete();` not work. and the statement that came out was `Data gagal dihapus` ... What wrong in my code?

Comment: i recently answered here may be helpful :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173994/deleting-a-specific-row-using-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

Hope it must be a GET

```
$id = $this->input->get("id", TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/m_pakar/delete/'.$result['pakar_id']);?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a>
```

controller :-

```
public function delete($id) {
 $this->general->where(array('pakar_id' => $id)); // will get you directly from url
```

For more :- [Deleting a specific row using codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173994/deleting-a-specific-row-using-codeigniter/)